# WP Запуск функции плагина повторяющийся по времени

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-плагины, cron

Пишу плагин для WP, в нем идет запрос на сторонний сервер с получение `json` данных с последующем записыванием в кастомные таблицы БД WordPress функцией `updateDataBase()`.

Вопрос - Как доработать данный плагин, что б на сервере происходило автоматическое обновление актуальных данных стороннего сервера по запуску функции каждый час?

- Пробую реализовать на локальном сервере через `cron` но почему-то прямой вызов файла  через

```
<?php

include 'E:\\OSPanel\\domains\\test.loc\\wpcontent\\plugins\\my_plugin\\admin\\uploadData.php';
updateDataBase();
```

не обновляет базу данных. Подскажите, как это реализуеться правильно ?

Answer (score 1):

В wordpress есть механизм WP-Cron. Используя его вы из своего плагина можете поставить хук на определеное время.

Ну и нужно будет настроить только один крон для /wp-cron.php - в том случае если этот крон не настроен.

Этот скрипт запускается системным кроном, а уже внутри него определяется какие функции и в какое время запускать. Т.е. WP-Cron реализует свой крон внутри сайта wordpress.

Есть инструкция для разработчиков плагинов ка использовать этот крон: https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/cron/